# HTML5 Data Attribute Sort

Tags: jquery, algorithm, html, sorting, frontend

I'd like to sort DOM elements that has data attributes defined for rating and date. What is the best way to implement sorting on the front-end with jQuery?

Sample code can be seen on: http://jsfiddle.net/gercheq/zhqXd/

Here is the desired functionality implemented with tables: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

There is a cool jQuery plugin that sorts DOM elements by attribute. You can find it here: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Example implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/statico/JNFFj/7/

Comment: I've been looking for something EXACTLY like this. Awesome to see I dont have to start from scratch!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the basic idea...

```
var sortedSet = $('#sort li').toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).data('rating') - $(b).data('rating');
});
```

You select the elements, convert them to a proper array, and then sort (the comparison function I used is an example, change it to suit your requirements).

[jsFiddle with *lowest* button](http://jsfiddle.net/zhqXd/8/).