# How to link using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have the following code and am using jquery mobile.  When I click on an element, it is not going to the "page2".  Any advice on how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
       <meta charset="utf-8"> 
       <title>My first jQuery Mobile code</title> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
            .custom_listview_img {
                margin:0px; 
                padding:0px;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:100%;
                height:150px;
            }
            ul {list-style : none; padding:0px;}
        </style>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".changePageButton").click(function() {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
                });        
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var url='http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=mRSTBQsB49CdMXTW&division=san-francisco&tag=restaurants&lat=37.871087&lon=-122.270913&callback=?';

        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
          $.each(json.response.deals,function(i,item){

             $("#results").append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="a" style="white-space:normal"><a class = "changePageButton" data-transition="slide"><li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-top">'+item.business.name+'</li><li class="custom_listview_img" style = "background-image:url('+item.images.image_smart+');"></li></a></ul>');

          });
        });   

  });

</script>

 </head> 
 <body> 

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c"> 

         <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"> 
               <h1>Dealoka</h1> 
         </div> 

         <div data-role="content" id = "results">
            <!-- Display results of parsing json here -->
         </div>   

    </div> 



<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true">
   <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">
      <p>Welcome to Page 2</p>
   </div> 
</div>

    </body> 
    </html>

<!-- Sort with jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560493/html5-data-attribute-sort -->
```

Comment: Your binding the event to early, try using event delegation or bind it after you attach it to the DOM.

Comment: BTW: For avoiding this amount of of HTML in your script you should better use a template library like [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) or [handlebar.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that at the time your binding your event to the `changePageButton` it is not yet part of the DOM, you need to either use event delegation or bind it after it's been attached to the DOM.

When you use event delegation, what you do is bind the event to a *higher* existing element (up to the `document` if necessary) in the `DOM` and check for the selector when the event bubbles up. Note that it's better to bind it to the closest *higher* element.

For example you can use the jQuery [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind the event using event delegation

```
$(document).on('click','.changePageButton', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
});
```

Comment: When I bend it to the higher existing element, how would I pass in different parameters to the next page based on which item the user clicks on this page?

Comment: If your asking how to get which element was clicked then you can get that from the event.currentTarget (the same as if you bind directly to the element).

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation because you are creating the event dynamically;

```
$(function() {
      $("body").on('click', '.changePage', function() {
          $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
          });        
      });
```

Comment: When I bend it to the higher existing element, how would I pass in different parameters to the next page based on which item the user clicks on this page?

Comment: @sharataka That's a different question altogether. Post a new question.

Comment: I was just asking because I was curious if this method of binding might impact how linking is done.